# Liferay - Find users by Full name

Tags: liferay

Is there a way to find Liferay users by FullName? I see there are methods to get a user by screen name and email address, but did not come across anything to get users based on full name. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch users from database, then dynamic query API can be used to write your own query to fetch matched details.

You may refer [this wiki page](http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Queries+2%3a+DynamicQuery+API) about writing dynamic queries.

If you like to fetch from search indexer, then faceted search may be used.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of users by their name you'll need to use one of `UserLocalServiceUtil`'s or `UserServiceUtil`'s `search` method. Like the one below for Liferay Portal 6.1:

```
public List<User> search(
        long companyId, String firstName, String middleName,
        String lastName, String screenName, String emailAddress, int status,
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params, boolean andSearch, int start,
        int end, OrderByComparator obc)
    throws SystemException
```

You can pass `null` for any field, including `obc`, if you have no other requirement or desired ordering.

Comment: But does this have something like full name. I just have full name and I can't go and split a username to first name and last name?

Comment: The best possible way is probably to use another search function that accepts keywords that returns `Hits`.